# Symbol table entry when using auto return type deduction with templates in C++

Tags: c++, auto, symbol-table, return-type-deduction

Does anyone know the reason why the output of `nm -C` on an executable that contained a templated function defined with `auto` return type deduction has the word `auto` in the symbol table?

Why does it need to know the return type was deduced? I had assumed that the compiler would just replace the `auto` with the actual type.

Below is an example followed by the output of `nm -c`

```
#include <iostream>

// Concrete function. Not called
float add(float a, float b){ 
        return a+b;
}

// Concrete function. auto return type deduction
auto add(int a, int b){ 
        return a+b;
}

// Templated function. One parameter
template <typename T>
auto add (T a, T b){ 
        std::cout << "One parameter\n";
        return a+b;
}

// Templated function. Two parameters
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add (T a, U b){ 
        std::cout << "Two parameters\n";
        return a+b;
}

int main()
{
        add(1,2);       // call concrete function
        add(3.0,4.0);   // generate and call one-parameter template function
        add(1,2.0);     // generate and call two-parameter template function    
    
        return 0;
}
```

And `nm -C` gives

```
001159 T add(float, float)
00123b W auto add<double>(double, double)
001173 T add(int, int)
00127c W auto add<int, double>(int, double)
```

Why does the compiler not instead generate

```
W double add<double>(double, double)
```

i.e. with the `auto` replaced by `double` for the templated function? That is what it will say if I replace the above by

```
template <typename T>
double add (T a, T b){ 
        std::cout << "One parameter\n";
        return a+b;
}
```

Comment: Most likely because the creators of the implementation thought that it might be useful (or it already is useful, somewhere). Why does it matter to you?

Comment: The word `auto` is not in the symbol table; it's the `-C` demangler reconstructing the mangling.

Comment: they are not equal anyway, you cannot declare with one while re-declare(implement) with another.

Comment: @Eljay The question is that there is a distinction in the symbol table. However it is stored, there is some information there that `nm` can use to determine that the function originally had `auto` type deduction. My question was why this was so? I thought that the naive approach would be that the compiler deduces a `double` and replaces the `auto` with `double` in the compiled code.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well I would like to understand why it might be important. Versus the naive understanding which is that after the compiler deduces the return type it would "replace" it with that type. Not exactly like a precompiler macro, but along the same lines.